# Javascript won't post into DIV?

Tags: java, php, javascript, json

So the console shows  that the data is being sent and received but for some reason (probably the conditional) nothing is posted in the specified div tag

```
var var_IDdatacheck  = <?php echo $javaid; ?>;
  var var_IDcheck = parseInt(var_IDdatacheck);

  //datacheck
  var var_numdatacheck  = <?php echo $datacheck; ?>;
  var var_numcheck = parseInt(var_numdatacheck);
 function activitycheck() {
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'feedupdate.php',
        data: {function: '3test', datacheck: var_numcheck, javaid: var_IDcheck},
        success: function (check) {
            console.log(check);
            var verify = JSON.parse(check);

            if (var_IDcheck < verify.id) {
                var_IDcheck = verify.id;
                for (var i=0;i<var_IDcheck;i++){
           $('#datacheck').html(verify[i]);

          }
          }
          setTimeout(activitycheck(),5000);
          },
    error: function(check) {
    console.log(check);
    setTimeout(activitycheck(),5000);
      }
      });
    } 


  $(document).ready(function()  {
   activitycheck();
  }); // document ready
```

Comment: Check your console or `alert(check);` to see if `check` is a valid JSON string.

Comment: I looked at my console 50 times  and I some how missed some html Tags hanging over it. Let me see if that was it

Comment: Wow that was what it was, I hate myself.

Comment: for some reason it wont post into the div "datacheck" but it is going through.

Comment: so you still have the problem? or not? if the problem is resolved, post the solution as answer and mark that as accepted.

Comment: no I solved it but I can't answer unfortunately, it was just a variable not being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your id from the JSON is a string, and you are comparing it with an integer

try

```
var verify = JSON.parse(check);

        if (var_IDcheck < parseInt(verify.id)) {
            var_IDcheck = parseInt(verify.id);
            for (var i=0;i<var_IDcheck;i++){
```

Comment: ok that actually makes a lot of sense. I tried it, still didn't work : /